# Jquery set selected value for cloned dropdown based on database

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, json, drop-down-menu

Hi i am using jquery to pull data from database n if the field has some value, i am calling clone function to create a dropdown list and using that value to set the selected value for dropdownbox. Like in code below database returns score so i am trying to set selected value of dropdown to score. ANDCriteria2 is the dropdown created using clone.  Even if i try to print ANDCriteria's selected value which by default should be total_balance, it show empty alertbox (`alert($('#ANDCriteria2').val()`)  as if the dropdown doesnt even exist

#### HTML

```
 <div id="ListOne">
    <div id="crit">
    <div id="innerDiv2">

    

    <select name="ANDCriteria2">
        <option value="total_balance">Total Balance</option>
        <option value="collector_code">Collector Code</option>
        <option value="score">Score</option>
        <option value="standard_desc">SDC</option>
        <option value="acct_age">Account Age</option>
        <option value="attempts_total">Total Attempts</option>
        <option value="phone_age">Phone Age</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

#### Jquery ready function

```
 (document).ready(function(){
    $('#lst').change(function(){    
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getter.php",
        data: "list=" + $(this).val(),      
        success: function(data){
    var items = JSON.parse(data)
    var andc2 = items[5];   
    if(andc2 === 'score               ') {
        clone ();   
            alert("BEFORE");    
   

 //$('#ANDCriteria2 option').eq(2).attr('selected', 'selected');
     //alert( $('.innerDiv2 ANDCriteria2').text());
         $('#ANDCriteria2 > .innerDiv2 >.crit  option[value=score]').attr('selected','selected');
       
        alert("AFTER");
```

Comment: your code is not complete

Comment: code is really long but i made sure i included everythign that was required. please assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean `$("[name='ANDCriteria']")` and **not** `$("#ANDCriteria")`. `#` is for ID based selection.

Culprit:

```
<select name="ANDCriteria2">
```

And you're using:

```
$('#ANDCriteria2 > .innerDiv2 >.crit  option[value=score]')
```

Comment: Thanks mattytommo i found out couple mins ago n edited the post.